# Downsides to "naive" estimation of longitudinal IRT factor scores?

Tags: panel-data, item-response-theory

I have a questionnaire administered at two time points. I would like to **estimate a latent factor score (theta) at each administration using Item Response Theory**. The ideal approach would be to model the change directly (e.g. [Longitudinal item response theory models in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104569/longitudinal-item-response-theory-models-in-r)), but my items are too highly correlated to estimate a solution.

As a workaround, I could **merge time 1 and time 2**, estimate the latent trait score for each unique response pattern, then fill the appropriate values for each participant at time 1 and time 2 (based on the response pattern).

I suppose that merging the two can affect the estimation of the the latent scores (which may or may not have important consequences). Any other potential downsides to this approach?