# Longitudinal IRT model specification using MIRT bfactor function

Tags: panel-data, model, item-response-theory, mirt

I try to specify / calculate a longitudinal IRT latent growth model to compare learning gains between three school years in a large data set. The test were administered by a computer adaptive testing approach, so each test taker solved a potentially different set of items.

I followed [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104569/longitudinal-item-response-theory-models-in-r) and [this tutorial](https://philchalmers.github.io/mirt/html/Longitudinal-IRT.html) to my extend of understanding.

**[Here, you can find my R Code and example data](https://gist.github.com/fgrng/543a4c98c286bcea41d27ad7ddf9ccc2).**

I used the "model"-parameter to define first-tier factors as common factors for items used in multiple school years. Therefore I defined a vector with incremented factor id for each set of items used in multiple years and "NA" for each item only present in a single year. See "first-tier factor loadings" in my R Code.

For the second-tier model specification I used the "model2" parameter and followed the [linear latent growth model outlined in the second part of the tutorial](https://philchalmers.github.io/mirt/html/Longitudinal-IRT.html). So I defined two time factor "intercet" and "slope". All item load with parameter 1.0 to "intercept" factor. Based on school year of the item the items load with parameter 0.0, 1.0 or 2.0 resp to the "slope" time factor. See "second-tier constraints construction" for my construction method and "second tier model string" for the resulting model string in my R Code.

When running the model I get the following error (see "model string construction and model fit" in my R Code):

```
Error in gp$gcov[np + i, np + i] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In model.elements(model = model$x, itemtype = itemtype, factorNames = factorNames,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

At this point I can't make sense of the error message. Is anyone able to comment on the plausibility of my model specification and the source of the error?

Thank you!

PS: I am also kinda confused about the parameter indexing in the model constraints. Is the a{i+2} parameter (notice a1 and a2 are "intercet" and "slope" time factor parameters) indexed by the i-th first-tier factor or by the i-th item? Should there be a skip in e.g. "(6,7,8, a5), (10,11,12, a6)" → "(6,7,8, a5), (10,11,12, a7)", because the item in column 9 is used in only one year?

Comment: I want to use a Rasch-Model with dichotomous answer variables.